# Disabling sentbox in postfix over Squirrelmail

Tags: email, imap, smtp, postfix, pop3

I have installed **POSTFIX** over `Squirrelmail` on CentOS Linux...

The services I have ran are:

```
service httpd
service ssl
service mysql
service postfix
service saslauthd
service dovecot
```

But I want to know :

How can I send mail but nothing go to my sentbox?

Thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just you should know a trick...

you can do:

```
cd /home/bobby/Maildir && chmod -w .Sent/
```

That works!!!